# How can I minio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, minio, webpack-5

when I use npx create-react-app my-app,then install minio and  import it,
last npm start the project,the Browser Console  24error,To solve the 24 error,I npm i stream-browserify crypto-browserify path-browserify stream-http https-browserify timers-browserify  buffer  url browserify-fs  polyfill,But this project console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
> at ./node_modules/levelup/node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js (readable.js:12:1)

Software version webpack is 5.64.4,react is  7.0.2, minio is 7.1.1

I hope this project can use minio

Answer (score 1):

MinIO client library is intended to be used in a server-side context, i.e., in a Node.js environment. It uses a lot of Node.js built-in modules such as 'fs', 'http', 'crypto', 'path', 'stream' and 'url', which are not available in the client-side JavaScript runtime environment.

One of the ways you can use MinIO in your client side is by creating a server-side application (you can use Express.js for this) that interacts with MinIO and exposes an API for your client-side React app to consume. This way, you are not exposing any sensitive data like the MinIO access and secret key in your client-side application.